# How to run .js file in console with playframework with intellij IDEA

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

I just created a static web project with .js file, now I want to run my .js file in console (console.log() with playFramework) but I can't ! How can I do ?
Thx

```js
var person = {
    firstName : "toto",
    lastName : "MOMO",
    age : 25
};

console.log(person);
```

Comment: Is your code client side or server side?

Comment: Where is your .js file located? How do you include that Javascript file in your UI page?

Comment: It's located in my project directory. To include that Javascript file, I just did new JS file inside my project directory

Comment: Okay, normally your custom Javascript files would go under the public directory, then accessed in your UI via `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/custom-functions.js")"></script>`, for example. That path there is relative to the "public" directory.

Comment: I just want to do like this video tutorial shows (part 1:53), rightclick->run: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiSFfpw3Btc&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_&index=2#t=63.831111

Comment: You can even just put the Javascript directly into your UI, if the only thing you want to do is the above bit of code that logs the person object to the console.

Comment: How to do it ?  please

Comment: Thank you for your support. I just installed node.js plugin, and everything work now.